# Logcat says: "Resource has unresolved theme attributes"

Tags: android, resources, warnings, drawable, logcat

logging my app my Logcat says: **WARN:** `... has unresolved theme attributes! Consider using Resources.getDrawable(int, Theme) or Context.getDrawable(int).`

the code which produces the warning:

```
    if (mCards.get(position).isFavorite()) {
        viewHolder.mIbStar
                .setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources()
                                          .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_is_fav));
    } else {
        viewHolder.mIbStar
                .setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources()
                                          .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_isnt_fav));
    }
```

I searched for this log, but didn't find anything useful. How knows whats the issue? The program is stable, so no Nullpointer..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not really know what the issue is but the logcat output seems quite clear. You have to replace `mContext.getResources().getDrawable` with `mContext.getDrawable`

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. I tried this earlier, but this method is for API >= 21... So maybe I will provide a method which loads the content for older versions.

Comment: now I changed the code to:
viewHolder.mIbStar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_is_fav);
seems to do the same..  ripple effect is still visible.. :)

Comment: Okay nice to hear that you worked it out. `setBackgroundResource` is the best solution, have not thought about that yesterday.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that the system can't find the associated theme to resolve these attributes values. 
That's why the logcat suggest you to use the [Resources.getDrawable(int, Theme)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)) method providing the theme, 
or to use the [Context.getDrawable(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDrawable(int)) method where the Context will use its current theme :

> Return a drawable object associated with a particular resource ID and
>   styled for the current theme.

Moreover, according to the Android official documentation :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int)

> This method was deprecated in API level 22. Use [getDrawable(int, Theme)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)) instead.

and more specifically

> Note: To obtain a themed drawable, use [Context.getDrawable(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDrawable(int)) or
>   [getDrawable(int, Theme)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)) passing the desired theme.

Consider replacing

```
mContext.getResources().getDrawable(int)
```

by

```
mContext.getDrawable(int)
```

such as proposes it the logcat.

Comment: But context.getDrawable(int) requires min API level 21

Comment: Indeed, I did not focus on this point. So, in this case, the best solution, as mentioned in comments by @ByteHamster, is to use [setBackgroundResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int))

Comment: Try to use ContextCompat. It provides backward compatibility to API 4.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue too. And I tried to find out the solution from the source code.

The log was printed at,

```java
    // android.content.res.Resources#getDrawable(int)
    public Drawable getDrawable(@DrawableRes int id) throws NotFoundException {
        final Drawable d = getDrawable(id, null);
        if (d != null && d.canApplyTheme()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Drawable " + getResourceName(id) + " has unresolved theme "
                    + "attributes! Consider using Resources.getDrawable(int, Theme) or "
                    + "Context.getDrawable(int).", new RuntimeException());
        }
        return d;
    }
```

It's a waring log, and if the `canApplyTheme` method of the Drawable returns true, then it will print the log.

So, different kinds of drawable will have different implementations of this method.

In my case, I used a GradientDrawable (defined by the xml drawable). So, let's have a look at the method of GradientDrawable.

```java
// android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable#canApplyTheme
    @Override
    public boolean canApplyTheme() {
        return (mGradientState != null && mGradientState.canApplyTheme()) || super.canApplyTheme();
    }
```

The GradientDrawable tries to get the value from `canApplyTheme` method of `mGradientState`. The `mGradientState` is a GradientState.

As for GradientState, its `canApplyTheme` is defined as below,

```java
// android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.GradientState#canApplyTheme
        @Override
        public boolean canApplyTheme() {
            boolean mGradientColorState = mGradientColors != null;
            if (mGradientColors != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mGradientColors.length; i++) {
                    mGradientColorState |= (mGradientColors[i] != null && mGradientColors[i]
                        .canApplyTheme());
                }
            }
            return mThemeAttrs != null
                    || mAttrSize != null || mAttrGradient != null
                    || mAttrSolid != null || mAttrStroke != null
                    || mAttrCorners != null || mAttrPadding != null
                    || (mTint != null && mTint.canApplyTheme())
                    || (mStrokeColors != null && mStrokeColors.canApplyTheme())
                    || (mSolidColors != null && mSolidColors.canApplyTheme())
                    || mGradientColorState
                    || super.canApplyTheme();
        }
```

So, if `mThemeAttrs` is not null, then the `canApplyTheme` method will return true.

As for `mThemeAttrs`, it's derived from `extractThemeAttrs` method of TypedArray. In the `extractThemeAttrs` method,

```java
// android.content.res.TypedArray#extractThemeAttrs(int[])
    public int[] extractThemeAttrs(@Nullable int[] scrap) {
        if (mRecycled) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot make calls to a recycled instance!");
        }

        int[] attrs = null;

        final int[] data = mData;
        final int N = length();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            final int index = i * STYLE_NUM_ENTRIES;
            if (data[index + STYLE_TYPE] != TypedValue.TYPE_ATTRIBUTE) {
                // Not an attribute, ignore.
                continue;
            }
        // ....
    }
```

So, obviously, if your resources has a TypedValue.TYPE_ATTRIBUTE typed attribute, then the log will print.

What is `TypedValue.TYPE_ATTRIBUTE`, is an attribute such as `?attr:xxxx`. So, the solution is:

First, try to remove the `?attr` values from your drawable. Then, if it's necessary for you, you have to replace the `Resource.getDrawable(Int)` method by `Context.getDrwable(Int)`.

Since, the `?attr` is associated with a theme. The Android system need to read real value from the theme. While the `Resource.getDrwable(Int)` use a `null` theme, so, the system is unable to get real value for your `?attr`.

If you are unable to use the `Context.getDrawable(Int)` method, since it's added in API 21. You can use the `ContextCompat.getDrawable(Context, Int)` method instead.